# Set bar colors on a Google Earth Engine chart

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, color, chart

I am trying to define a set of colours by month on a ui.Chart.image.series, however, after adding the .style line, no changes are made. I would like to have a different bar color for each month, the palette should repeats over different years.

My code so far looks like this:

```js
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('TRMM/3B43V7')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('1998-01-01', '2019-06-30'));
var precipitation = dataset.select('precipitation');
var precipitationVis = {
  palette: ['blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'],
};
Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 3);
Map.addLayer(precipitation, precipitationVis, 'Precipitation');


// Define a region of interest as a buffer around a point.
var geom = ee.Geometry.Point(-74.08384, 9.42503).buffer(500);

// Create and print the chart.
var mean_prec_chart = ui.Chart.image.series(precipitation, geom, ee.Reducer.mean(), 12);
mean_prec_chart.setChartType('ColumnChart');
mean_prec_chart.style({color:['blue','red','green','brown']});
print(mean_prec_chart);
```

[image: Resulting chart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to rework the data calculated in `ui.Chart.image.series()` into a feature collection. Then you will add a property for each different month and you can plot each month using `ui.Chart.feature.groups()`.

```
// put the data similar as presented in the chart above in a featureCollection
var featsPrecipitation = ee.FeatureCollection(precipitation.map(function(image){
  var precip = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(),geom, 12);
  var groupProp = image.date().format('MM');
  return ee.Feature(null, precip).copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
                    .set('month', groupProp);
}));
print(featsPrecipitation)

var mean_prec_chart = ui.Chart.feature.groups(featsPrecipitation, 
                                              'system:time_start', 'precipitation', 'month');
mean_prec_chart.setChartType('ColumnChart')
// by default, all months will have another colour. But you can set them by your own
// mean_prec_chart.style({color:['blue','red','green','brown']});
print(mean_prec_chart);
```

The chart will visually look a bit different due to the distance between the bars, but the data is similar.

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/755d930833399b9e381bd7b76174ef33)

Comment: Thanks @Kuik, this is what I was looking for, however, I am struggling now to make the bars a bit wider.

Comment: I didn't succeed either. Maybe ask on the forum.

Comment: This method does not seem to be working for me. Even the linked code doesn't seem to work. ```chart.style``` isn't changing the chart, it's just returning the 'ActiveDictionary'. See [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ui-chart-style) for the relevant docs.

Comment: It looks like the proper way to do this in 2022 is to set the color using ```chart.setOptions({colors})```. See [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3b07a73e0777c68dd1cc6238c6f94ba6) for an updated example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Kuik, that helped a lot.
I just found out how to make the bars wider:

```
    .setOptions({
      ....,
      isStacked: true
    });
```

otherwise, there is space for another bar next to it, thus making the bars narrow.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.